# Mongo indexing in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Not sure I'm understanding indexing mongo queries in Meteor. Right now, none of my queries are indexed. On some of the pages in the app, there are 15 or 20 links that instigate to a unique mongo query. Would each query be indexed individually?

For example, if one of the queries is something like:

```
 Template.myTemplate.helpers({
 ...
 if (weekly === "1") {
   var firstWeekers = _.where(progDocs, {Week1: "1"}),
   firstWeekNames = firstWeekers.map(function (doc) {
    return doc.FullName;
 });
 return Demographic.find({ FullName: { $in: firstWeekNames }}, { sort: { FullName: 1 }});
 }
 ...
 })
```

How would I implement each of the indexes?

Comment: Indexing is not built into MiniMongo, Meteor's client-side implementation of the MongoDB API.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly minimongo (mongo on the client-side) runs in memory so indexing is much less of a factor than on disk. To minimize network consumption you also generally want to keep your collections on the client fairly small making indexing on the client-side even less important.

On the *server* however indexing can be critical to good performance. There are two common methods to setup indexes on the server:

1. via the meteor mongo shell, i.e. `db.demographic.createIndex( { FullName: 1 } )`
2. via setting the field to be indexed in your schema when using the *Collection2* package. See [aldeed:schema-index](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-schema-index)

Comment: Thanks, Dr. Floyd. Keeping collections on the client small, for me, isn't really a possibility since the the app is an in-house app that needs the entire collections in the browser. It's not a subscription based app where users sign into their own data. But the collections aren't huge anyway.

Comment: I'm sort of confused with the first method. Using the mongo shell, if I have multiple indexes for multiple queries spread throughout  the app, how does the server know which index goes with what query?

Comment: You index a document *key* not a *query*. You can also create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-compound/) on multiple keys that are queried together. If you want to understand how mongo is using indices, try [cursor.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.explain/)